# Summernote Toolbar customization Issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, custom-controls, summernote

I'm trying to delete some features from summernote editor toolbar. But when I write following code to customize it,

```
$('.summernote').summernote({

  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']]
  ]
});
```

it gives given below error in console (developer tools) and toolbar disappears (because of error).

```
Uncaught TypeError: b[t[1][u]] is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah looks like you're using a different version of summernote. Upgrade to the latest and it should work: (example) https://jsfiddle.net/ggfk1h3x/

```
jquery/1.9.1
bootstrap/3.3.6
summernote/0.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!Mine was because of the simple **'**  .
I changed it to " "

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
      ["style", ["bold", "italic", "underline", "clear"]]
      ["font", ["strikethrough", "superscript", "subscript"]]
      ["fontsize", ["fontsize"]]
      ["color", ["color"]]
      ["para", ["ul", "ol", "paragraph"]]
      ["height", ["height"]]
    ]
});
```

and it works like a charm!!